# How to I check if R client is installed on a Hadoop cluster?

Tags: r, hadoop

I have a CentOS based Hadoop Cluster (HDP). I would like to know what is R Client and how do I check if R client is installed on a node?

Comment: I got a down vote for this question, because this is off-topic and not related to programming. I agree, but then, where should I post this question? If it is off-topic then can this question be please moved to the right forum, which I don't know exists. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run following command to check if package is installed or not:

```
[terminal~]$yum info R
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: ftp.daum.net
* epel: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
* extras: ftp.daum.net
* updates: ftp.daum.net
Installed Packages
Name : R
Arch : x86_64
Version : 3.1.2
Release : 1.el6
Size : 0.0 
Repo : installed
From repo : epel
Summary : A language for data analysis and graphics
URL : http://www.r-project.org
License : GPLv2+
```

Here you can see all the details.

```
[terminal~]$ R
```

Above command will take you to the R terminal.

RClient is a client available in Rserve package(renamed to RSClient, RServe 1.7 onwards). [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html) is the server which responds to the requests from clients.

**Installation:**
It needs to be installed first from R terminal(Rserve and RSClient packages).

```
install.packages("Rserve") 
install.packages("RSClient")
```

Or from linux shell : `[terminal~]$ R CMD INSTALL Rserve_1.8-5.tar.gz`

**Launching Rserver:**

You can launch it from R using:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
// load RSClient 
library(RSClient)
```

However, Rserve is a stand-alone program, so it can be started directly as well. If you installed Rserve from a source package (on unix), type:

```
R CMD Rserve
```

Please refer [RClient](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RSclient/docs/Rclient) with example in R script for more details.

Comment: Does 'R Client' mean R-package or R-Language. I am confused by the term R-Client. Can you please clarify this.

Comment: @KurioZ7: RClient is a client package in R, which is used to communicate with Rserver. Updated the answer, please refer the detailed description

Comment: ok thanks. I understood. (wonder why this question  has got a down vote?)_